# How to use Scheduled actions in Process Builder to Invoke a flow after the Criteria evaluates to true

Tags: process-builder, criteria, scheduled-action

can someone help me with this scenario.

I need to send a survey to the closed cases based on the case origin.
If the case origin is Facebook the survey should be triggered immediately.
If the Case origin is Email the survey should be triggered after 48 hours.

I'm unable to set the scheduled actions immediately after the criteria is evaluated to true it shows me the immediate actions before the Scheduled actions. How can I create a scheduled action after the criteria is checked and send the Survey after 48 hours.

I'm attaching the screenshot for reference[image].

Comment: Just put your actions in scheduled actions, if you don't want to do anything immediately, you can skip that.

Comment: Thanks @rahul gawale . I did that and it worked. If Immediate action is  blank and I create actions in scheduled actions, after checking the criteria it is skipping the immediate action and excuteing the scheduled actions.